# Java Canvas and Sprites Error

Tags: java, swing, java-canvas

I have a given Canvas class, I want to load a Sprite with a special celltype and then draw it on my Canvas. I'm new to GUI and Canvas modelling, with the part of Code below I always get an "Unhandled type IO Exception Error " in line 3 where I Implement my sprite loader. I can easily draw Rectangles and else but I fail at loading my Sprite and convert it to an Image.

```
private class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public SpritesheetLoader SL=SpritesheetLoader.defaultLoader();
    private Spritesheet S=SL.getSpritesheet("graphics/sprites/equipment/chest/tnecksweater-female");
    Image I=S.getCel(0);


    /**
     * Creates a new canvas object
     */
    public Canvas() {
        super(true);
        super.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0)); // middle green
    }

    /**
     * Redraws the canvas
     * 
     * @param g The graphics context to redraw with
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        synchronized (UIPanel.this) {
            if (canvasDrawer != null) {
                canvasDrawer.draw(g);
            }
        }

        g.drawImage(I, 10, 10, this);

    }

}
```

Edit:

```
public class SpritesheetLoader {

private String filename;

private Map<String, ZipEntry> spritesheets = null;

// XML parser
private DocumentBuilder xmlParser = null;

private ZipFile zipFile;


public SpritesheetLoader(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    try {
        this.xmlParser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException exn) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exn);
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void printDocument(Document doc, OutputStream out) {
    // code by http://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho
    try {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), 
                new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


public void init() throws IOException {
    if (spritesheets != null) {
        return;
    }

    spritesheets = new HashMap<>();

    this.zipFile = new ZipFile(this.filename);
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipIterator = zipFile.entries();
    while (zipIterator.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry z = zipIterator.nextElement();
        if (z.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
            String name = z.getName().substring(0, z.getName().length() - 4);
            spritesheets.put(name, z);
        }
    }
}


public Spritesheet getSpritesheet(String name) {
    ZipEntry entry = spritesheets.get(name);
    if (entry == null) {
        return null;
    }
    SpritesheetParser parser = new SpritesheetParser();
    parser.parseToplevel(getData(entry));
    return parser.getSpritesheet();
}


private InputStream getData(ZipEntry entry) {
    try {
        InputStream s = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        return s;

    } catch (IOException exn) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exn);
    }
}


private InputStream getDataForFilename(String data) {
    try {
        ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry(data);
        if (entry == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing file entry: " + data);
        }
        InputStream s = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        return s;

    } catch (IOException exn) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exn);
    }
}


public Set<? extends String> getSpritesheetNames() {
    return spritesheets.keySet();
}

private static SpritesheetLoader DEFAULT = null;


public static SpritesheetLoader defaultLoader() throws IOException {
    if (DEFAULT != null) {
        return DEFAULT;
    }
    DEFAULT = new SpritesheetLoader(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "prgpr" + File.separator + "graphics.zip");
    DEFAULT.init();
    return DEFAULT;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SpritesheetLoader loader = defaultLoader();
    System.out.println(loader.getSpritesheetNames());
    System.out.println(loader.getSpritesheet("graphics/sprites/equipment/chest/tnecksweater-female"));

}


private class SpritesheetParser {
    private Spritesheet spritesheet;


    public Spritesheet getSpritesheet() {
        return spritesheet;
    }


    public Element parseDoc(InputStream indoc) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = xmlParser.parse(indoc);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return doc.getDocumentElement();
    }


    public Element includeIfNeeded(Element elt) {
        if (elt.getTagName().equals("include")) {
            return parseDoc(getDataForFilename(elt.getAttribute("file")));
        }
        return null;
    }


    private void parseImageSet(Element elt) {
        if (spritesheet != null) { // already have a spritesheet; obey override semantics
            return;
        }
        String filename = elt.getAttribute("src");
        EnumSet<DyeChannel> dyeChannels = EnumSet.noneOf(DyeChannel.class);
        int splitIndex;
        if ((splitIndex = filename.indexOf('|')) > 0) {
            int index = splitIndex + 1;
            for (; index < filename.length(); index++) {
                switch (filename.charAt(index)) {
                case 'R': dyeChannels.add(DyeChannel.RED); break;
                case 'G': dyeChannels.add(DyeChannel.GREEN); break;
                case 'B': dyeChannels.add(DyeChannel.BLUE); break;
                case 'C': dyeChannels.add(DyeChannel.CYAN); break;
                case 'M': dyeChannels.add(DyeChannel.MAGENTA); break;
                case 'Y': dyeChannels.add(DyeChannel.YELLOW); break;
                case 'W': dyeChannels.add(DyeChannel.WHITE); break;
                }
            }
            filename = filename.substring(0, splitIndex); 
        }
        BufferedImage bufferedImage;
        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(getDataForFilename(filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        spritesheet = new Spritesheet(bufferedImage, dyeChannels);
        if (elt.hasAttribute("width") && elt.hasAttribute("height")) {
            spritesheet.setCelDimensions(Integer.parseInt(elt.getAttribute("width")), Integer.parseInt(elt.getAttribute("height")));
        }
    }

    int intAttribute(Element elt, String name) {
        if (elt.hasAttribute(name)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(elt.getAttribute(name));
        }
        return 0;
    }


    private void parseAnimation(Element elt, String name) {
        Direction direction = Direction.DEFAULT;
        switch (elt.getAttribute("direction")) {
        case "up": direction = Direction.UP; break;
        case "down": direction = Direction.DOWN; break;
        case "left": direction = Direction.LEFT; break;
        case "right": direction = Direction.RIGHT; break;
        }

        Animation animation = new Animation();
        boolean looping = true;

        NodeList nl = elt.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = nl.item(i);
            if (n instanceof Element) {
                Element animationStep = (Element)n;

                int xoffset = intAttribute(animationStep, "offsetX");
                int yoffset = intAttribute(animationStep, "offsetY");

                switch (animationStep.getTagName()) {
                case "frame":
                    int index = intAttribute(animationStep, "index");
                    animation.addCelSequence(new CelSequence(
                            index, index, intAttribute(animationStep, "delay")).setOffsets(xoffset,  yoffset));
                    break;
                case "sequence":
                    animation.addCelSequence(new CelSequence(
                            intAttribute(animationStep, "start"),
                            intAttribute(animationStep, "end"),
                            intAttribute(animationStep, "delay")).setOffsets(xoffset, yoffset));
                case "end":
                    looping = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        animation.setIsLooping(looping);
        spritesheet.addAnimation(name, direction, animation);
    }


    private void parseAction(Element elt) {
        String actionName = elt.getAttribute("name");

        NodeList nl = elt.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = nl.item(i);
            if (n instanceof Element) {
                Element actionPart = (Element)n;
                switch (actionPart.getTagName()) {
                case "animation": parseAnimation(actionPart, actionName); break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void parseToplevel(InputStream docStream) {
        parseToplevelElement(parseDoc(docStream));
    }


    public void parseToplevelElement(Element body) {
        if (body == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!body.getTagName().equals("sprite")) {
            System.err.println("Not a <sprite>");
            return;
        }
        NodeList nl = body.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) { 
            Node n = nl.item(i);
            if (n instanceof Element) {
                Element elt = (Element) n;
                switch (elt.getTagName()) {
                case "imageset":
                    parseImageSet(elt);
                    break;
                case "action":
                    parseAction(elt);
                    break;
                case "include":
                    parseToplevelElement(includeIfNeeded(elt));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you surround the part where you load the image with a `try- catch`-block (catching an `IOException`)?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean surround the part where I load the image, I throw an exception in my SpritesheetLoader function but where should I trycatch it Inside my Canvas class

Comment: Can you add the code of the `SpritesheetLoader` and `Spritesheet` classes? Does the spritesheet loader check whether the file "graphics/sprites/equipment/chest/tnecksweater-female" exists? Should that file path have an extension (like ".png" or ".jpg")?

Comment: SpritesheetLoader added, in our given example we can load id without .png or .jpg